# 'numpy.float64' is not callable in Flask

Tags: python, numpy, flask

I have very strange behavior with my script. If I'm simply passing parameters to get_results, everything works just fine, but when I'm trying to pass parameters from JSON (using POST request), my script fails. What's the problem?
Thanks!

```
   def get_results(condition, arr):
        if len(arr) != 0:
            res_arr = [finding_condition(arr[x], condition) for x in range(len(arr))]
            final_temp = list(map(lambda x: cond_freq(condition) * x, res_arr))
            final = [final_temp[k] for k in range(len(final_temp))]
            result = np.prod(np.array(final))
            print(result)
        else:
            result = cond_freq(condition)
            print(result)
        return result



    @app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
    def foo():
        if not request.json:
            abort(400)
        print(request.json)
        condition = request.json.get("condition")
        findings = request.json.get("findings")
        v = get_results(condition,findings)
        print(v)
        return v

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"condition\": \"Fibroadenoma\",\"findings\": [\"Mass\"] }" http://localhost:8000/
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py", line 871, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Comment: Flask wants you to return a `string` or a `Response` instance, not a `numpy.float64` instance.

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much! Saved my day.